# php replace a word with optional parentheses

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i want delete only last `"world"` in string below.
i want match parentheses too.. it should be optional.

for example both:

```
$string = 'this is my world, not my (world)';
$string = 'this is my world, not my world';
```

result should be `this is my world, not my`

the code:

```
  $string = 'this is my world, not my (world)';
  $find = 'world';
  $replace = '';
  $result = preg_replace(strrev("/$find/"),strrev($replace),strrev($string),1);
  echo strrev($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP (PCRE) you may use this [conditional regex construct](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.conditional.php):

```
(.*)\h+(\()?world(?(2)\)|\b)
```

And replace with:

```
$1
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(.*)`: Match 0 or more characters at start (greedy or longest possible match) and capture it in group #1
- `\h+`: Match 1 or more horizontal whitespaces
- `(\()?`: **Optionally** match opening `(` and capture it in group #2
- `world`: Match text `world`
- `(?(2)\)|\b)`: If capture group 2 is present then match `)` otherwise match word boundary

**PHP Code:**

```
$repl = preg_replace('/(.*)\h+(\()?world(?(2)\)|\b)/', '$1', $str);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mkmDI6/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could just do a regex replacement with an alternation:

```
$input = 'this is my world, not my (world)';
$output = preg_replace("/(?:\(world\)|\bworld\b)(?!.*\bworld\b)/", "", $input);
echo $input . "\n" . $output;
```

This prints:

```
this is my world, not my (world)
this is my world, not my
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

```
(?:              match (but do not capture)
    \(world\)    either (world)
    |            OR
    \bworld\b    world
)
(?!.*\bworld\b)  assert that no other occurrence of world or (world) occurs
                 later in the string
```